# How do I get ASGORE's Health and Defense down quickly?

Tags: undertale

So the ASGORE fight is pretty hard and I wan't to make it so that it's easier! How do I do that? I've tried talking to him but it doesn't work! He keeps killing me with the stupid spinning fire attacks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's actually two ways to go about this...** (Warning SPOILERS, Please hover your mouse over the boxes.)

> On your first turn, keep talking to ASGORE until his DEFENSE and ATTACK are lowered. You MUST keep talking to ASGORE every turn or it will say *"It seems talking won't do any more good."*  (It will also do that when his DEFENSE and ATTACK are lowered)

.

> Way two: If you got the butterscotch pie from TORIEL, Don't eat it until you are fighting ASGORE and then eat it. His ATTACK and DEFENSE will drop as the smell of the pie will remind him of something.